# GetEndpoint is always null and RouteValues is always empty in custom exception handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I'm attempting to build up a `ProblemDetails` object within a custom exception handler.
I've noticed that the `RouteValues` is always empty and `GetEnpoint` is always `null` and I'm unsure why.

For reference here is how I'm attempting to access the aforementioned values:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseExceptionHandlerMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    => app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
    {
        AllowStatusCode404Response = true,
        ExceptionHandler = async context =>
        {
            var exception = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()?.Error;
            
            // The endpoint is always null.
            var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint()?.ToString();

            // Always empty.
            var routeValues = context.Features.Get<IRouteValuesFeature>()?.RouteValues;

            // Other stuff.
        }
    });
```

And here is the request/response pipeline:

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("OurPolicy");

// Registering the custom exception handler here.
app.UseExceptionHandlerMiddleware();
app.UseStatusCodePages();

// Other middleware registrations.
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Within this extension method we're mapping our minimal API endpoints.
app.AddPeopleEndpoints();

await app.RunAsync();
```

Again, for reference here is what `AddPeopleEndpoints` looks like.

```
public static class AddPeopleEndpoints
{
    public static void AddPeopleEndpoints(this WebApplication app)
    {
        app.MapGet("/people/{id:guid}", GetPerson)
            .WithTags("people")
            .WithName(nameof(GetPerson));

        private static async Task<Results<Ok<Person>, NotFound>> GetPerson(Guid id)
        { /* Some implementation */ }
    }
}
```

I've tried rearranging the order that we're registering our endpoints and the exception handler but the results are always the same.

Is there something we're doing wrong here?

I took a look at what `MS` is doing for the default implementation of the exception handler which can be viewed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/12b5fa046bf6578b5429a95cd2cf1b652319658a/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/DeveloperExceptionPage/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.cs#L105C24-L105C24). In terms of how we're attempting to access the values it's the same.

Anyone else try this before? If so is there anything I've shown with how our pipeline is configured that could cause these values to always be empty/`null`?

Comment: by looking at your code it seems there is issue in the middleware registration order, could you try below code: `var app = builder.Build();
    app.UseCors("OurPolicy");
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseExceptionHandlerMiddleware();
    app.UseStatusCodePages();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.AddPeopleEndpoints();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        // ... any additional endpoint registrations
    });
    await app.RunAsync();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `Endpoint` and `RouteValues` from `IExceptionHandlerFeature`.

```cs
var exceptionHandlerFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
var endpoint = exceptionHandlerFeature.Endpoint;
var routeValues = exceptionHandlerFeature.RouteValues;
```

Comment: Yeah this worked, thank-you.